# One Page Website - Url Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a one page website with jQuery. i'm trying to figure out how I change the URL of the website (E.g. www.test.be) when I click the right menu item. Right now it just gives (www.test.be/#) But I'd like it to say (www.test.be/work) for example. Also when I refresh I'd like the website to be on the page where the user was, not the first page. Would this be possible to achieve?

Comment: share some relevant code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Build a regular website first (to achieve the goal "on the page where the user was" most effectively while being robust and search engine friendly) then use Ajax with [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to manipulate the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this with jQuery alone, it would be an uphill struggle. You're better off using a client-side MVC framework.

There are a number of client-side MVC frameworks available that should do this. I generally use [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), and using its routing you would easily be able to accomplish this kind of thing. It makes it very easy to define client-side routes with hashes and assign views to those routes. As long as you don't mind the URL being www.test.be/#work, that will be fine

You might also want to check out AngularJS as an alternative, but I can't speak for how easy it would be to implement this in Angular.

Comment: This reads as more of a product recommendation than an answer, and the question is asking how to do the routing *without* using fragment ids in the URLs.

Comment: @Quentin OP would clearly benefit from using a client side MVC framework for this project. I merely mentioned Backbone because I'm familiar with it and I know it can do this kind of thing from personal experience